# Same code doesn't run properly when split into multiple cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook, same set of codes, if typed in the same cell, runs properly. But if they are split up in separate cells, doesn't give the result properly. I can't grasp the logic behind this.

The code below works properly when they are put together in the same cell:

```
train_predictions = linear_model.predict(train_feed_input_testing) 
test_predictions = linear_model.predict(test_feed_input) 
train_predictions_series = pd.Series([p['predictions'][0] for p in train_predictions]) 
test_predictions_series = pd.Series([p['predictions'][0] for p in test_predictions])

train_predictions_series, test_predictions_series
```

Output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\Users\Sharon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8ji2dirb\model.ckpt-130
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\Users\Sharon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8ji2dirb\model.ckpt-130
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
(0      20.289957
 1      14.288830
 2      21.357958
 3      32.151848
 4      15.634930
          ...    
 399    14.102298
 400    36.894062
 401    21.191111
 402    18.937582
 403    24.520029
 Length: 404, dtype: float32,
 0       4.261360
 1      21.573397
 2      25.178829
 3      12.356460
 4      26.815147
          ...    
 97     33.873730
 98     15.573816
 99     11.774225
 100    20.550158
 101    34.921947
 Length: 102, dtype: float32)
```

But if I split them up (same line of code in the next cell in the same jupyter notebook), it gives an empty series object...

```
train_predictions_series = pd.Series([p['predictions'][0]for p in train_predictions]) 
train_predictions_series
```

Output:

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that jupyter notebook have a separate scope in cells. I know some functions have scope just over cell their written in.

Comment: But if that's the case, we shouldn't able to use the variable 'train_predictions_series' outside of the scope of the cell right. But it is working. The problem is I cannot reproduce the same 4-line code in separate cells.

Comment: This is wrong, "I have a feeling" is not proper technical knowledge. And it is not how Jupyter cells work.

Comment: I cant write comments yet so i did write an answer, i have no technical knowledge but couple days before i saw someone have similar problem about scope in JN, i tought it might be helpfull.

Comment: You may be hitting a "hidden state" problem in your kernel namespace? Or one of them? When and where are you restarting the kernel? Is the separate cell example in a different notebook or same one?  Plus your first posted code block seems to have two lines as one? And you aren't illustrating fully what happens actually when you break them up. You skip to end of the 'separated' example showing an empty series. You can run two different notebook & post them as gists & share them here so when you post things are clearer and more thorough. Most likely though in doing that you'll sort it out.